# Mysterious Bug Within Python Loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, random

So, I was working on some basic finance, trying to simulate a number of random stock price paths, when I encountered this inscrutable bug in the code. I try to `print` out a single number many times in a nested loop, but for some reason the number varies.

My code so far:

```
# Imports.

%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *

# Error-producing section - randnorm holds a 10x10 vector of normally distributed 
# random numbers, used in calculating my price path.

sims = 5
intervals = 5
r=.02
T=1
sigma=.15

paths = [[1]*intervals]*sims
randnorm = [[np.random.normal() for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]
# print(randnorm)

for i in range(sims):
    for j in range(1,intervals):
        paths[i][j] = paths[i][j-1] * exp((r - .5*sigma**2)*(T/intervals) + sqrt(T/intervals)*randnorm[i][j-1])
        print(paths[0][1])
```

I knew something was wrong with my previous code, so I tried debugging by printing in each loop, and I get this,

```
0.5937221173702402
0.5937221173702402
0.5937221173702402
0.5937221173702402
1.4849274521869171
1.4849274521869171
1.4849274521869171
1.4849274521869171
0.860018700453769
0.860018700453769
0.860018700453769
0.860018700453769
1.0709782525755074
1.0709782525755074
1.0709782525755074
1.0709782525755074
0.7184834195858915
0.7184834195858915
0.7184834195858915
0.7184834195858915
```

What gives? I seriously do not know where I could be wrong here. It's not my random numbers, which are all different, or an index issue.

Comment: What did you *expect* the output to be?

Comment: You're aware that you are repeatedly printing `paths[0][1]`, not `paths[i][j]`?

Comment: I am, and all those numbers are supposed to be the same, correct?

Comment: Dunno, you tell us.  As @jonrsharpe asked, what is it you expect?

Comment: I expected the same number repeated many times, whatever the formula calculated it to be. The fact that `paths[0][1]` is being interpreted like `paths[i][1]` is throwing a hitch in my code elsewhere.

Comment: What is `paths`?

Comment: It's a 10x10 vector that tries to simulate a vector evolve over time from starting index 0 for each row.

Comment: Psychic debugging time: `paths` was defined as `[[something]*something]*something` or something like that, causing it to be a list of a bunch of references to the same sublist.

Comment: Next time, show us something that actually defines all the variables it uses.

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem without seeing how `paths` is declared/created.

Comment: @user2357112 Second that. (The psychic debugging part.)

Comment: I didn't realize in my haste that I didn't include how I declared `paths`, so I apologize on that point; it is now included.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be something with how your array was created, as making an `np.ndarray` of `sims`x`intervals` in size results in the outputs remaining the exact same (either `0.0` or some zero-like floating error of `0.x*10-8`).

```
paths = np.ndarray((sims, intervals))
for i in range(sims):
    for j in range(1,intervals):
        paths[i][j] = paths[i][j-1] * exp((r - .5*sigma**2)*(T/intervals) + sqrt(T/intervals)*randnorm[i][j-1])
        print(paths[0][1])
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Without more explanation of what `paths` actually is, and how it was made, and it's pre-loop values, it's impossible to diagnose the issue.

---

***Edit***

After the question was updated, a resolution would be to just use [np.ones](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) to make the matrix.

```
paths = np.ones((sims, intervals))
```

The current implementation is causing the issue in the marked duplicate, where each list is a reference to the same list, so modifying one will modify all of them.

Comment: I included in my code how I declared `paths`, which I accidentally omitted earlier.

Comment: @Coolio2654 I've updated the answer, even though it was marked duplicate.